# Converting Bitmap To Mat through Utils.bitmapToMat changes its color

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android

I'm using the following code to convert Android Bitmap into OpenCv Mat, however it is changing its colors:

```
public synchronized static Mat BitmapToMat(Bitmap image) {

    Mat mat = new Mat();
    org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(image, mat);

    return mat;
}
```

**Original Image:**

[image]

**Converted Image:**

[image]

Any help please!!
Thanks

Comment: you're just displaying it wrong. OpenCV internally uses BGR instead of RGB color format, so you have B and R channel swapped. You can use `cv::cvtColor(..., cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: @Miki thanks that worked, please post that as an answer to vote it up for the public benifit